# How to hide all items in a private void method you've created?

Tags: c#, button, hide, windows-forms-designer

so I created my own private void that can create buttons

```
        private void addButtonsToForm()
        {

           for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
         {
               Button currentNewButton = new Button();
               currentNewButton.Size = new Size(20, 30);
               currentNewButton.Location = new Point(20 + 25 * i, 420);
               currentNewButton.Text = ((char)(65 + i)).ToString();
               currentNewButton.Click += LetterClicked;
               letters[i] = currentNewButton;
               this.Controls.Add(letters[i]);
          }

        }
```

The buttons are alphabets and will be accessed when the user wants to choose a letter ... but the problem is I'm trying to figure out how to go back when the user clicked or selected a button..

Originally I wanted to do was i could just hide all the buttons created and just make the previous button visible but for some reason it only hides the only button that is clicked

```
     //this is under private void LetterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      Button selectedLetter = (Button)sender;
      selectedLetter.Enabled = false;
```

i thought of stupid codes like
`addbuttonstoform().visible = false;` but of course that won't work.. but you might get an idea to where i want to go.... it's a bit confusing to explain... I'm new in c# and i'm creating a guess the word game so help could be great..

Comment: Are you trying to hide a _method_ or a _button_? Your title says one thing, but the post seems to say another. Please fix your question so that it makes sense, and so that it includes a good [mcve] that shows what you're trying to do, along with a detailed explanation of what you've tried, what the code does now, and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: @Peter Duniho Thank you for reminding me that.. I'm actually trying to hide all the buttons created in a method and I assumed that if you hide a method example: `method.visible = false;` it will hide everything that is created in it that is showing inside the forms designer.. that is why my question is like that :)

Comment: i also know there is no such code exist (the example i showed) but it's an idea on what i want to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution for your problem. See below:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Alphabets
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Button[] _letters;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AddButtonsToForm();
        }

        private void AddButtonsToForm()
        {
            _letters = new Button[26];
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            {
                Button currentNewButton = new Button
                {
                    Name = "BtnLetter"+ ((char)(65 + i)),
                    Size = new Size(20, 30),
                    Location = new Point(20 + 25 * i, 420),
                    Text = ((char) (65 + i)).ToString()
                };
                currentNewButton.Click += LetterClicked;
                _letters[i] = currentNewButton;
                this.Controls.Add(_letters[i]);
            }
        }

        private void LetterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedLetter = (Button) sender;
            //hide all other buttons
            foreach (var letter in _letters)
            {
                if (letter.Text != selectedLetter.Text)
                {
                    var buttons = this.Controls.Find("BtnLetter" + letter.Text, true);
                    buttons[0].Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Gabrielle Euseb if the answer helped you, please mark as accepted answer by clicking the tick button. thanks

Comment: i'd love too but i only have 12 reputation but as soon as i get 15 i would up vote it immediately!